# python pool map and apply_async

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to learn about `map` and `apply_async` in the following example (adapted from [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/08/02/python-201-a-multiprocessing-tutorial/)).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from functools import partial
import time

def operate(number1=None, number2=None, op=None, timeout_list=None):
    if op == "+":
        return number1 + number2
    elif op == "-":
        time.sleep(1)
        return number1 - number2
    elif op == "/":
        time.sleep(6)
        return number1 / number2
    elif op == "*":
        time.sleep(10)
        return number1 * number2
    else:
        print("+, -, /, *")

timeout_list = Manager().list()
kwargs = {"number1":10, "number2":7, "timeout_list":timeout_list}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ops = ["+", "+", "-", "*", "/", "+"]
    pool = Pool(processes=len(ops))
    result = pool.map(partial(operate, kwargs),ops)
    print(result.get(timeout=5))
```

I'm trying to do three things:

1. pass `op` as a keyword to `map` after partially setting `operate` with `number1` and `number2` (but I'm currently getting an `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`)
2. get the operations `*` and `/` to timeout and return `*` and `/` (respectively) as results from timing out in `timeout_list`
3. how would I achieve the following with `apply_async` and what's the difference?

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: ... pass op as a keyword to map

**You have**, put the following in `def operate(...` to see what you do:

```
def operate(number1=None, number2=None, op=None, timeout_list=None):
    print('pid:{} operate({})'.format(os.getpid(), (number1, number2, op, timeout_list)))

>>>pid:4932 operate(({'number1': 10, 'number2': 7, 'timeout_list': <ListProxy object, typeid 'list' at 0xf6c0afac>}, 
                     '+', 
                     None, 
                     None)
                   )
```

1. `number1` == `kwargs dict`
2. `number2` == `ops[x]`
3. `op` == `None`, because you use only **2** Parameters
4. `timeout_list` == `None`, because you use only **2** Parameters

> **Question**: ... partially setting operate with number1 and number2

**You haven't**, do the following to see what `partial` do:

```
print(partial(operate, kwargs))

>>>functools.partial(<function operate at 0xf70ed194>, 
                      {'number1': 10, 'number2': 7, 'timeout_list': <ListProxy object, typeid 'list' at 0xf70f38ec>})
```

> **Question**: ... getting an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get')
>   Read the **AttributeError** carefully!

`.map(...` returns a pure Python `list` not a *result object*!

```
 print(result)
>>>[None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

> **Question**: 2. get the operations * and / to timeout and return ...

Unclear what you are asking?

> **Question**: 3. how would I achieve the following with apply_async ...

Before you get further get Step 1 and 2 running.